# Creating a jQuery tabs shortcode

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs, shortcode

I am trying to create a jQuery tabs shortcode for WordPress this is my code in my functions.php for some reason the tabs show etc but they don't change?

```
add_shortcode('tabs', 'tabs_group');
add_shortcode('tab', 'tab');

// this variable will hold your divs
$tabs_divs = '';

function tabs_group( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $tabs_divs;

    // reset divs
    $tabs_divs = '';

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        'id' => '',
        'class' => ''
    ), $atts));  

    $output = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs '.$class.'"  ';

    if(!empty($id))
        $output .= 'id="'.$id.'"';

    $output.='>'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';
    $output.= '<div class="tab-content">'.$tabs_divs.'</div>';

    return $output;  
}  


function tab($atts, $content = null) {  
    global $tabs_divs;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        'id' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'active'=>'n' 
    ), $atts));  

    if(empty($id))
        $id = 'tab_item_'.rand(100,999);

    $activeClass = $active == 'y' ? 'active' :'';
    $output = '
        <li class="'.$activeClass.'">
            <a href="#'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>
        </li>
    ';

    $tabs_divs.= '<div class="tab-pane '.$activeClass.'" id="'.$id.'">'.$content.'</div>';

    return $output;
}
```

Here is whats in my header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And on my page I have:

```
[tabs]
[tab title="tab" active="y" id="home"]home[/tab]
[tab title="tab2" active="n" id="about"]about[/tab]
[tab title="tab3" active="n" id="help"]help[/tab]
[/tabs]
```

EDIT!!

```
function tabs_header() {

//wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_register_script( 'add-jquery-js', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),'',true  );
wp_register_script( 'add-jqueryui-js', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'),'',true  );


wp_enqueue_style( 'add-jquery-js' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'add-jqueryui-js' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabs_header' );
```

Comment: No errors in the [browser console](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console)? Also see: [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). You have to compare a working simple HTML/JS code with the code your site outputs.

Comment: No errors in console all information shows fine but it does not change tab

Comment: For converting HTML/JS into WordPress, **you have to compare** a working code with WP result. How are you enqueuing the scripts? Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/556/12615).

Comment: put them in header also tried enqueing them and they still dont work.

Comment: For some reason my enqueue scripts isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really know what you're doing, [don't enqueue external jQuery sources](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45440/12615). Most of WordPress/jQuery bugs are because of this. Let WP use its bundled jQuery version and you're good to go.

You're not showing your *Tabs* script, but I suppose you have one. This is how I would enqueue a *jQuery Tabs* script ([I have this working plugin at GitHub for an Audio Player](https://github.com/brasofilo/ResponsiveAudioPlayer)):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_so_17856211' );

function enqueue_scripts_so_17856211()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'tabs-css', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/tabs.css' 
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'tabs-js',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/tabs.js', 
        array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui' ), 
        false, 
        false 
    );
}
```

Note that `your-script.js` is [being enqueued](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) with `jquery` and `jquery-ui` dependencies.